# How can i delete user profile picture in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

Is there a way that I can remove/delete user profile picture through programing? or How can i override existing image with my new one?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the UI? If you could explain more about what you're trying to accomplish that would be helpful

Comment: Yes because i have custom Layout for user profile page. for that I user my custom tpl file other than user--profile.tpl.php

Comment: have you investigated https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-picture.tpl.php/7 ?

Answer (score 1):

use code below in hook_user_delete($account)

```
// Load user by using user id
$user = user_load($uid);
// Get file id of profile photo
$fid = $user->picture->fid;
// Load the file object
$file = file_load($fid);
// delete profile photo from.
file_delete($file);
// Unset the image object (my case it's 'picture')
unset($user->picture);
// Save the user
user_save($user);
```